# ipython multiline string with escaped newlines

Tags: python, ipython

I'm facing a strange behavior in IPython and wonder if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong. Basically, when I paste this code

```
print('''\
a \
a
a
a
a
a
a
a \
a
''')
```

to my IPython input prompt, it shows this `...:` to ask for more input. The only way to get back to a new input prompt is to press ctrl+c. However, the command is processed as expected by a regular python prompt. Also, when I remove the last `\`, even IPython will eat it:

```
print('''\
a \
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
''')
```

Is this a normal behavior?

**Update:**

Bug confirmed and fixed upstream ([#10157](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10157))

Comment: Are you pasting with `%paste` or `Ctrl-V`?

Comment: I'm using ipython version 3.2.1. It does not matter if I paste with ctrl+v or with the middle mouse button.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I see this problem too. Maybe opening a bug in ipython's github repository is  a good idea.